# RadUpload From Telerik doesn't work inside sharepoint 2010 sites?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, telerik

I have RadUpload from telerik inside Sharepoint 2010 Site Page , but DeleteSelected and Select Buttons Don't work

Is There any idea or workaround???

Answer (score 0):

Do you receive any JavaScript errors when clicking on the 'Delete' button? The same functionality works fine in a simple ASP.NET page.